# locally modifying a python library (sklearn, linux)

Tags: python

I want to modify a couple of functions from sci-kit learn - adding a few lines at most.

Working on my Windows machine at home I can (and did) edit the source code directly (though I realize this is risky in view of future projects...). 
Now, however, I'm working on a remote Linux server where I don't have privileges to edit  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/.../

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Copy the lib folder to your project directory, modify it and import it from there rather than from the dist-packages

Comment: Use [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) or [`viritualenvwrapper`](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). This will create a virtual environment to execute your projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending of your modifications you can:

- Override method/function in a new python module
- Install library in a different folder for your project

  ```
  pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" package_name
  ```
- Copy the library in your project (pip or git or cp)